# writing route in form to store request in database

Tags: php, laravel, controller, resources

Can anyone please explain me the difference between the methods below; writing routes with using resource controller

```
{!! Form::open(['route', 'posts.store']) !!}
{!! Form::open(['action' => 'PostController@store']) !!}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [tour]. You may also want to check [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask], and how to create a [mcve]. Post the code you have tried and the errors you have received. Be as specific as possible as it will lead to better answers.

Answer (score 0):

Will create a form that points to a named route:

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => 'posts.store']) !!}
```

Will create a form that points to an action in a controller:

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => 'PostController@store']) !!}
```

You can read more about it in the [Forms & HTML](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html#opening-a-form) section in the Laravel documentation.